# Need help understanding how to simply and combine this problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry to bug the community with such a simple problem but finals are near and my professor is MIA. I was able to copy down part of the solution, but I don't understand how he got to that part, and I need help finishing it. The problem is as follows.

Simplify and Combine:

$$8x^3+4x-3x(4-3x+2x^2)$$

So I look at the first part as $(8x^3+4x-3x)$ and the second part as $(2x^2-3x+4)$. I did this to make the problem look much more simpler to me. Now here is where I am having an issue. The professor really didn't give me much chance to write down the solution but this is what I got for the first part:
$$8x^3+4x-3x$$
to
$$x(x^2+4-3)$$
to
$$x(x^2+1)$$
to
$$x(x+1)(x-1).$$

My issue is, where the **** did the 8 go? and how can I do the next part? I am reviewing for my final, and I would really appreciate help, especially since a tutor costs $120 an hour. :-(

Comment: You are correct in noticing that there is a problem.  $8x^3+4x-3x$ is **not** equal to $x(x^2+1)$.  Also $x^2+1$ is **not** equal to $(x+1)(x-1)$.  Finally, as mentioned in the comments below, $(8x^3+4x-3x)(4-3x+2x^2)$ is **not** equal to $8x^3+4x-3x(4-3x+2x^2)$ (you cannot throw parenthesis into places they didn't exist before unless you are very careful and understand what is going on, for now just never do that).  Counterexample, $2-2(1+3)=2-2(4)=2-8=-6$  while $(2-2)(1+3)=(0)(4)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the confusion in your question and in the comments, there are two possible interpretations as to what the original question was.

$$8x^3+4x-3x(4-3x+2x^2)$$

and

$$(8x^3+4x-3x)(4-3x+2x^2)$$

These are **not** equal and as such you cannot just willy-nilly throw extra parenthesis in places and expect the answers to come out the same.

---

$$\begin{array}
~~8x^3+4x-3x(4-3x+2x^2) & \\
= 8x^3+4x+(-3x)(4-3x+2x^2) & \text{by definition of subtraction}\\
= 8x^3+4x+(-3x)(4)+(-3x)(-3x)+(-3x)(2x^2) & \text{by distributivity}\\
= 8x^3 + 4x - 12x + 9x^2 - 6x^3 & \text{by computing multiplications}\\
= (8-6)x^3 + 9x^2 + (4-12)x & \text{by grouping terms}\\
= 2x^3 + 9x^2 - 8x & \text{by computing additions/subtractions}
\end{array}$$

---

$\begin{array}
~~(8x^3+4x-3x)(4-3x+2x^2)\\
=(8x^3+x)(4-3x+2x^2) & \text{by simplifying inside of parenthesis first}\\
=8x^3(4-3x+2x^2) + x(4-3x+2x^2)&\text{by distributivity}\\
=32x^3-24x^4+16x^5 + 4x - 3x^2+2x^3 & \text{by distributivity}\\
=16x^5-24x^4 + (32+2)x^3 -3x^2+4x & \text{by grouping like terms}\\
=16x^5 - 24x^4 + 34x^3 - 3x^2+4x & \text{by computing additions/subtractions}
\end{array}$

---

As you see, the simplification of the first interpretation is a polynomial of degree 3, whereas the second interpretation is a polynomial of degree five.

The idea that you can choose to factor polynomials can be helpful if you are going to *keep* them factored in the end, but in a question like this, I found find it pointlessly time consuming.  As for attempting to factor the second copy of the expression, you can as you noted correctly convert $(8x^3+4x-3x)$ to $x(8x^2+1)$, however, that is as far as you are able to go with real numbers.  If you wish to factor that any further you will require the use of complex numbers (and given the level of the question seems entirely unreasonable).  Similarly, you cannot factor $(4-3x+2x^2)$ without the use of complex numbers as well.  As such, we see that the second interpretation has exactly one real root (at $x=0$) and four complex roots.

Finally, as I mentioned in my comment above, $(x^2+1)\neq (x+1)(x-1)=(x^2-1)$

> (except in fields of characteristic two, which you will not hear about for a very long time)

Answer (score 1):

$8x^3+4x−3x(4−3x+2x^2)$

Distribute the "$-3x$" to every element in the parentheses. i.e, $-3x(4-3x+2x^2) = -12x+9x^2-6x^3$.

And then you just combine like-terms AKA you add things together if they have the same "$X$" exponential. So you can add all the $x^2$ together or the $x$'s together but you can't add $x^2$ with $x$.

So you get $8x^3+4x-12x+9x^2-6x^3 = 2x^3+9x^2-8x$.

Comment: the problem needs to be simplified first, the problem 8x3+4x−3x(4−3x+2x2) is separated like so (8x3+4x−3x) (4−3x+2x2), so if i were to choose your method then i would have to multiply each value with everything in the parentheses one by one, then combine. My professor did not do that, he simplified it first then combined.

Comment: Note that $8x^3+4x-3x(4-3x+2x^2)\neq(8x^3+4x-3x)(4-3x+2x^2)$. Which one is the one you're tasked with?

Comment: the problem looks like this 8x3+4x−3x(4−3x+2x2), but my professor instructed us to look at it like (8x3+4x−3x)(4−3x+2x2). He simplified both and then combined.